# Navbar cortado en móviles bootstrap responsive

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

El problema surge cuando mi navbar lo visualizo en chrome, sale cortado y no sé como hacer que ocupe toda la pantalla. Dejo mi código HTML y una imagen, espero me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light navbar-toggleable-sm" >
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <span class="navbar-text">Pozoleria | La casa de Docha</span>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">           
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nava-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nava-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nava-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nava-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Amigo puede que algo de tu estructura te esté fallando, por ejemplo si tienes una imagen sobrepuesta donde está la barra de navegación... Revisa

Comment: Gracias Carlos, fue lo que tu comentaste. Saludos

Comment: Genial amigo... me alegra que hayas resuelto

Comment: Gracias a ti Carlos por tomarte el tiempo de revisar la duda :) :)

Answer (score -1):

El problema fue efectivamente que tenían un elemento que provocaba que la página se alineara a la derecha como comento @Carlos Duarte. Era un iframe de google maps.

Comment: Hola! Estes es el espacio de respuestas, y para mantener el sitio limpio, solo se permiten publicar respuestas. Te recomiendo hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Así aprenderás como funciona el sitio y podras extraer lo mejor de él.